# Understanding cmder hotkeys config

Tags: conemu, cmder

I want to make Cmder's key bindings similar to tmux. So that I will be able to easily switch between them.

Every command in tmux starts with `ctrl+b` followed by another key. in example `ctrl+b,"` will add a vertical pane in tmux, and I'd like to bind the same keys to cmder's 'Split: Duplicate active ‘shell’ split to bottom: Split(0,0,50)'.

the settings window shows these drop down boxes, and I can't find how to set the to `ctrl+b,"`.

[image]

Comment: The answer is simple: ConEmu doesn't support chords.

Comment: So are there any workarounds / solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug where if you use the drop down for Ctrl first it will not work.

Choose the hotkey first, and then use the drop down menus on the left to choose the rest of your modifiers such as Ctrl+Alt B